# Regex - How to replace a specific character in a string after being typed only once?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to limit an input field to only numbers and the possibility of a "+" sign just at the string's [0] index. The idea is to let the user type their phone number, I have come up with this:

```js
function main() {
  let phone = document.getElementById('phone');
  let phoneRegex = /[a-zA-Z]|[-!$%^&*()_|~=`{}[\]:";'<>?,./]/;
  phone.value = phone.value.replace(phoneRegex, '');

  console.log(phone.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="phone">
<button onclick="main()">Run</button>
```

The thing is, this works fine, but I want to limit the first character to only a digit or a "+" sign, characters coming from index [1] and on should only be numbers.

I can't come up with an idea on how to solve this

Comment: The question mark operator does what you need: https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html

Comment: In addition to all other comments/answers is the OP aware of [predefined character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) and their short hand forms? Which e.g for *digit characters only* would be `\d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as a starting point (you'll probably want to expand it further to account for total string length, delimiters like `-`, etc.):

```
let phoneRegex = /\+?\d+/;
```

`+` in a regular expression has a special meaning, so when we want to match the literal character "+" then we need to escape it. And following it with the `?` character makes it optional:

```
\+?
```

Next, `\d` followed by `+` will match any sequence of one or more digits:

```
\d+
```

You can see a visualization of this pattern [here](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5C%2B%3F%5Cd%2B%2F).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to limit the first character to only a digit or a "+"
> sign, characters coming from index [1] and on should only
> be numbers.

The regex:

```
/^\+?\d+$/
```

means:

*From the beginning, one or zero `+` signs, then one or more numbers until the end.*

Note the following regex symbols:

- `*` - zero or more
- `+` - one or more
- `?` - zero or one

Comment: No worries - I started to write my answer before (probably moments before) @Donut's answer displayed, so I didn't initially see it. Donut's answer is a good one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late in this game, but adding one more solution for me and other's future references.

I came up with this solution which works for me:

```
/^(\+|[0-9])?[0-9]{12}$/
```

Thanks